# Some libraries don't work when running JNLP file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jnlp, java-web-start

Everything works in my Java EE project when I'm running it from Netbeans, but when I deploy it in Glassfish server and run downloaded JNLP file, some added libraries don't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any error messages? Have checked your logs?

Comment: *"..some added libraries don't work. Any ideas?"*  Maybe they're just sleepy, give them a good night's rest and try them in the morning.  Maybe they're lazy.  Give them a flogging.  Something else?  You might try 1) Describing what you expected to see. 2) Describing what actually happened (complete with output copy/pasted from the Java Console).  ..Short of that, and potentially a great deal more information from you, I doubt anyone here can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Any library that your program needs that is not part of the standard Java SE distribution must be referenced in the JNLP file.  Part of your JNLP file might be:

```
<resources>
   <j2se version="1.6+"/>
   <jar href="serdarsProject.jar" main="true"/>
   <jar href="lib/activation.jar"/>
   <jar href="lib/mail.jar"/>
   <jar href="lib/jcommon-1.0.16.jar"/>
   <jar href="lib/log4j-1.2.jar"/>
</resources>
```

Since mail.jar and activation.jar are included with Java EE, you would not need these in your library when running a Java EE project in netbeans.

Turn on the Java Console in your preferences.  In Windows, you can do this through the Control Panel - the option is found in the Java Control Panel.  When some function in your program fails to work, you will probably see a specific error message in the output window.  This might help you determine which jar libraries you need to include.

Comment: glassfish will figure out which jars to include?