# How to add a library for JWS app.?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3, java-web-start

I'm deploying a swing client that require some external library to run.
How can I made them available to download via `<jar href="library.jar"/>` in the JNLP? Is there a configuration to make them available or a folder where I can put them?

Answer (score 1):

As outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11129876/230513), the JAR must be accessible using the relative path specified in the `href` attribute. There's a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9443588/230513).